# Django: Should I use include or extends tag to create a FAQ?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm creating a FAQ on my website. It's a page with lots of Q and A. Each Q/A block can be complex HTML (not simple text).

I'd like to avoid to repeat the same HTML code for Q and A structure.
That's why I was thinking of creating a q-and-a.html and including the file as many time as questions I have, doing somethink like:

```
<div class="my-faq">
    {% include q-and-a.html with question="What is life?" answer="It's complicated, son." %}
    {% include q-and-a.html with question="Ping?" answer="Pong!" %}
    <!-- Lots of other question/answer here -->
</div>
```

But in that case, I'll need to pass HTML, not texte. AFAIK, the `{% include ... with %}` tag does not allow me to transfer HTML to the included file. Even if it was possible, it would be hard to maintain.

Then, I was thinking the `{% extends %}` tag is probably a best choice regarding my need. But actually, this would work if I have 1 question only since the extends tags can be put one time per template.

My case is pretty simple so I guess there is a simple solution, but I'm a bit lost with the include/extends logic to follow here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you meant: `question="What is life?" answer="42"`

Comment: django is so much more smarter than we think. Think of include as just a template extraction of your inline html content. Just use the `mark_safe` tag, and it would render the html if you pass it html. One way I would handle this is, have all the Q & A in the database, and load it via a view - That way, you need one forloop to render all the html content.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually thinking of putting the Q&A in my database. I'm not especially pleased to create a query when not necessary, but you're right it will be easier to manage, and to write template with a for loop!